# Since current through capacitor (between the plates) is displacement current, what is the current flowing to the leads of a capacitor called?

Tags: capacitor, current, physics, capacitor-charging

Since there is no conduction current through the capacitor, what ***is*** the current that flows between the battery and the leads of the capacitor while the plates are charging (or discharging) to their respective polarities?  Is it still conduction current even though [conduction] current is not completing the circuit "through" the capacitor?  Or is it more like a transfer of charge between the battery and the capacitor plates making it more like drift current?  I realize that these are not free carriers, but I'm struggling to reconcile the fact that there is no "physical current" through the capacitor (although displacement current current acts as a "real" current inducing a magnetic field), and the fact the I tend to think of conduction current as requiring a closed loop (ie, conduction from battery + to battery - terminals).

Is a closed loop equivalently created (or simulated) as far as the battery is concerned by the collection of electrons from the positive plate on the positive terminal of the battery and the expulsion of electrons from the battery negative terminal to the  negative plate of the capacitor making it "look" to the battery as if electrons flowed all around the circuit?

I apologize if the question is not clear.  I understand displacement current between the plates of the capacitor (insulator between the plates, so no conduction).  I just want to better understand the physics of the current flowing between the battery terminals and the capacitor plates.

Comment: That is just ‘regular’ current flowing if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: It is conduction current, as far as I know. There is no need for a closed loop to form; KCL deals with conduction current, although if you apply it to just one plate of a capacitor, you'll get a contradictory equation (pretty much the same thing that happens when you apply Ampère's law without Maxwell's correction to the same scenario). By the way, I think the Physics Stack Exchange is better for these questions.

Comment: why did you write "displacement current current acts as a "real" current inducing a magnetic field"? When treating capacitors in a quasi-static perspective, it is customary to leave the magnetic field out of the picture. Anyway, the problem you are facing stems from the fact that, much in the same way KVL no longer works inside an inductor, KCL is no longer valid inside a capacitor. If you look at an inductor from the outside you can still pretend KVL works and voltage can be expressed as potential difference; if you look at a cap from outside you can pretend the current goes through it.

Comment: Ah, you meant that the current is generating a field around itself like normal current would. Not that you are considering the effects of the field generated . Ok, anyway, the current is conduction in the leads and displacement between the plates. In conduction the field is pushing the charge in the metal, in displacent the field is 'calling' an equal but opposite charge on the other plate.

Comment: Thanks, Sredni.!.. but...from, say,  the battery + terminal to the capacitor plate connected to it, how is current flowing?  There is no potential difference (so where is the E-field?), and the circuit ends at the plate (it is open)....so, how is conduction current working in that case? I know it is conduction...I just can't explain and be consistent with what I know should be the case.....Thank you

Comment: If you assume perfect conductors, ie with infinite conductivity, a zero electric field suffices in maintaining a finite current (it's a 0/0 limit oddity). In a real conductor, say copper, the field is E=j/sigma and is very small. You will find a small voltage drop due to the finite resistance of the leads. Basically the field produced by the battery shows up almost in its entirety between the plates, while it gets almost obliterated in the conductor by the field generated by the surface and interface charges.